# Is possible to dynamically change table name in LINQ c#?

Tags: linq, dynamic

I am developing something like dashboard for our DataLoader tool(loads data batches to our MS CRM Dynamics application]. I am using .Net 8 and C# Blazor server up. I have created bdContext using scaffolding tool included in the EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. Then I have designed IQueryable LINQ select which will be displayed in RadzenDataGrid. Basic selects work very well. But I need more complicated/advanced dynamical use of the LINQ select.

```cs
records = dlContext.Dls
    .AsQueryable()
    .Select(s => new Statistics()
        {
            **Import = s.Import**,
            CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy,
            CreatedOn = s.CreatedOn,
            StartedOn = s.StartedOn,
            CompletedOn = s.CompletedOn,
            FileName = s.FileName,
            InstantRun = s.InstantRun,
            StatusCode = s.StatusCode,
            Success = **s.DlAccountAnonymizes**.Where(sc => sc.StatusCode == (int)ImportStatus.Successful).Count(),
            Failed = **s.DlAccountAnonymizes**.Where(fc => fc.StatusCode == (int)ImportStatus.Failed).Count(),
            Totals = **s.DlAccountAnonymizes**.Count()
    });
```

The field **s.Import** holds data about the type of the load(names of the data tables where detailed data about the import are). In example loads are called DlAccountAnonymizes or AgreementUpdate. These tables are related to main table class as collections:

```cs
    public virtual ICollection<DlAccountAnonymize> DlAccountAnonymizes { get; set; } = new List<DlAccountAnonymize>();

    public virtual ICollection<DlAccountBiupdate> DlAccountBiupdates { get; set; } = new List<DlAccountBiupdate>();

    public virtual ICollection<DlAccountCreate> DlAccountCreates { get; set; } = new List<DlAccountCreate>();

    public virtual ICollection<DlAccountUpdate> DlAccountUpdates { get; set; } = new List<DlAccountUpdate>();
```

And I need for each DataGridRow that the select uses for the fields **Success, Failed and Totals **table name, which is related to the main data row. In example in main table there is type DlAccountUpdates, so I need that in the count there would be:

```cs
s.**DlAccountUpdates**.Where(sc => sc.StatusCode == (int)ImportStatus.Successful).Count()
```

Is there any possibility to do it in single Linq select?

I tried any standard ways for the string change. With no success.

Comment: How many rows are in Dls? It it possible to process them in memory? Then you could use arbitrary C# code. So basically i'm asking if you can replace the `AsQueryable` with `AsEnumerable`

Comment: @TimSchmelter DLs have about 30000 records. I can change the result to Enumerable or List.